# How to influence the start of a folded <span> line?

Tags: html, css

I have a text make up of three `<span>` and I do not understand the rules applied when folding them:

```html
<span style="font-family: sans-serif; 
font-weight: normal; 
color: black; 
background-color: white; 
border-color: darkblue; 
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 5px; 
padding: 3px 3px 3px 7px;
text-align: center;
">
    ℹ
</span>
<span style="
font-family: sans-serif; 
font-weight: bold;
color: white; 
background-color: darkblue;
border-color: darkblue;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
">
    This is some text
</span>
<span style="font-family: sans-serif; 
font-weight: normal; 
color: black; 
background-color: white; 
border-color: darkblue; 
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 5px; 
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
">
    This is more text, a longer one which will eventually fold. Some more words.
</span>
```

If the width of the browser is reduced, the message folds and overlaps the upper parts.

**How is the folding calculated?** (what is taken into account to decide that the text will be placed at a specific distance?)

And therefore: **what are the parameter(s) which influence the shift to the bottom of the next line of text?** (in other words: what to change so that the second line starts lower)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). From the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced):

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box
>   start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do
>   with the 'line-height'. **But only the 'line-height' is used when**
>   **calculating the height of the line box**.

```css
span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-color: darkblue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span style=" font-weight: normal; 
color: black; 
background-color: white; 
padding: 3px 3px 3px 7px;
text-align: center;">
    ℹ
</span>
<span style="
font-weight: bold;
color: white; 
background-color: darkblue;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
">
    This is some text
</span>
<span style=" 
font-weight: normal; 
color: black; 
background-color: white; 
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
line-height:35px;
">
    This is more text, a longer one which will eventually fold. Some more words.
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a particular reason why you applied `line-height:35px;` to the last section only? (or is it just because it is expected that this is the only one which will fold)

Comment: @WoJ you can apply to any one :) it will be the same. OR you can also apply it to their container (the body in this case) it will also be the same. It's a bit tricky but for an easy explanation it's like  we consider the max line-height to find the height of the line-box (it's more complex than this in reality)

Comment: @WoJ you may check this for more in deepth explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282391/understanding-css2-1-specification-regarding-height-on-inline-level-boxes/52284184#52284184