# List of blocks and inline-blocks show incorrect vertical spacings

Tags: html, css

I have a simple list of **div**s, with the exception that one div is an `inline-block`

```
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
<div>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</div>
...

div {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px; 
}

div:nth-child(5) {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #bada55;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/2uLb0frk/6/)

all looks just fine (font-size :20px). However, when I change the font-size to 10px things are getting weird

[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/2uLb0frk/7/)

Although I can fix it by adding

```
body { font-size: 0 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/2uLb0frk/8/)

I still don't understand why it did work with a line-height and font-size of 20px ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the inline one has to be positioned inside the line height of its container.

If you set the container's `line-height` to `10px` (*the `body` in your examples*) it will work fine.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri more presicely there is two line height that need to be considered, the one of the container and the one of the element. Some useful links to understand how things works : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282391/understanding-css2-1-specification-regarding-height-on-inline-level-boxes / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280267/why-is-there-space-between-line-boxes-not-due-to-half-leading

Comment: @gabriele : for precise definition, an inline element should be placed inside the line box defined by the line height (not inside the line height)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes your are right. It was a laymans explanation :)