# 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots (inline-block)

Tags: html, css

My question is about the height of **inline-block** which contains **only inline boxes**

```
<div style="display: inline-block; 
            height: auto; 
            border: 1px solid red
"><span style="font-size: 16px; 
               line-height: 16px; 
               background-color: yellow;
">x</span></div>
```

In the example above I expect the following:

- The height of the content area of the inline-block would be **16px** because it contains only inline elements
- The height of inline elements determined by "line-height" which equals **16px** in my case but in reality, its height **18px**

Inline-block element should create block formatting context (MDN):

> **A block formatting context is created by at least one of the following:**
>
> - the root element or something that contains it
> - floats (elements where float is not none)
> - absolutely positioned elements (elements where position is absolute or fixed)
> - **inline-blocks (elements with display: inline-block)**
> - table cells (elements with display: table-cell, which is the default for HTML table cells)
> - table captions (elements with display: table-caption, which is the default for HTML table captions)
> - anonymous table cells implicitly created by the elements with display: table, table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group (which is the default for HTML tables, table rows, table bodies, table headers and table footers, respectively), or inline-table
> - block elements where overflow has a value other than visible
> - display: flow-root
> - elements with contain: layout, content, or strict
> - flex items (direct children of the element with display: flex or inline-flex)
> - grid items (direct children of the element with display: grid or inline-grid)
> - multicol containers (elements where column-count or column-width is not auto, including elements with column-count: 1)
> - column-span: all should always create a new formatting context, even when the column-span: all element isn't contained by a multicol container (Spec change, Chrome bug).
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

The height of block formatting context roots which contains only inline elements defined by a height of line boxes (from spec):

> #### 10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots
>
> In certain cases (see, e.g., sections 10.6.4 and 10.6.6 above), the height of an element that establishes a block formatting context is computed as follows:
>
> If it only has inline-level children, the height is the distance between the top of the topmost line box and the bottom of the bottommost line box.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#root-height

Height of line box equals "line-height" (from spec)

> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading

If I change **"display: inline-block"** on **"display: inline-flex"** it works as expected

Thanks

Comment: you have two line-height and you only changed the one of the element inside keeping the one of the parent by default

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/52282391/8620333 (almost a duplicate) and you will understand the calculation

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yup, it makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @TemaniAfif

He was right the reason of `18px` for height was in `line-height` of `div` element. `div`'s `line-height` specify **minimal height** of line boxes

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level
>   elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes
>   within the element.

In my case `div` doesn't specify `line-height` property so it has default value equals `normal`.

> **Name:** `line-height`
>
> **Value:**    `normal` | `<number>` | `<length>` | `<percentage>` |
>
> **inherit Initial:**  `normal`

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#leading

If `line-height` value is `normal` then computed value depends from user agent.
But spec recommends to use value 1.0 to 1.2 of element's font-size. Looks like usually this value are equals to `font-size * 1.2` but it's also depends from font's metrics like `ascent`, `descent` and `em-box` (so result would depends from font-family).

> **normal**
>
> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value
>   based on the font of the element. The value has the same meaning as
>   . We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2.
>   The computed value is 'normal'.

If you know font's metrics like `ascender` and `descender` and font-size which you would use on the web you can calculate `line-heigh` by `(ascender + Math.abs(descender)) * font-size / (units_per_em)`

```
function lh(ascender, descender, unitsPerEm, fontSize) {
  return (ascender + Math.abs(descender)) * fontSize / unitsPerEm;
}
```

[image]
[image]

In the pictures above `ascender=5000`, `descender=-200`, `units_per_em=1000` and `font-size=48px` so `line-height=(5000 + 200) * 48 / 1000 = 249.6` (`lh(5000, 200, 1000, 48)`)
[image]

`ascent`, `descent` font's properties are shipped with font and defined by font's creator.
You can use *[FontDrop!](https://fontdrop.info/)* service to get information about font

Some implementations details from Chromium(Webkit) relates to line-height

```
LayoutUnit ComputedStyle::ComputedLineHeightAsFixed() const {
  const Length& lh = LineHeight();
  // Negative value means the line height is not set. Use the font's built-in
  // spacing, if avalible.
  if (lh.IsNegative() && GetFont().PrimaryFont())
    return GetFont().PrimaryFont()->GetFontMetrics().FixedLineSpacing();
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/core/style/computed_style.cc#1835

FixedLineSpacing

```
 float line_gap = SkScalarToFloat(metrics.fLeading);
  font_metrics_.SetLineGap(line_gap);
  font_metrics_.SetLineSpacing(lroundf(ascent) + lroundf(descent) +
                               lroundf(line_gap));
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/fonts/simple_font_data.cc#123